# delay between each value in an array

Tags: java, android

i have a number of values stored inside a Long[] which is used for vibration method in android,

```
        int dot = 100;
        int dash = 220;     
        int short_gap = 200;    
        int medium_gap = 700;  
        vibIndicator = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        vibPattern = new long[] {0, dash, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, medium_gap};          
        for (int i = 0; i < vibPattern.length; i++)
        {
            if (vibPattern[i] == 100)
            {
                vibIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.White);
            }
            else if(vibPattern[i] == 220)
            {
                vibIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
            }

            try 
            {                   
                Thread.sleep(vibPattern[i]);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                //
            }
        }
        Vibrator vibrator;
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);       
        vibrator.vibrate(vibPattern, -1);
```

i need to change the background colour of the textview accordingly when it becomes either a dash or a dot

the application would hang for a period of time(i assume its under the sleep state) and only shows the last background colour when it resumes

Comment: You say it's not working, but you don't say what it is doing. Why is what it is doing different than what you expect?

Comment: Other comments: You defined variables so that you array construction was not just a list of magic numbers. But then when you go to compare the current value, you use magic numbers. You are also only using `i` to index the array, so you might as well make it a foreach loop.

Comment: sorry for not explaining. yes, i mean it is not working that it would only show the last background colour and not change accordingly as per pattern change

Comment: Where is the code that is actually doing the vibration? I would expect this and changing the display would be tightly coupled, or at least be event driven.

Comment: @unholysampler i have updated the code with the vibration part. i make use of the native android vibration method which takes in a Long[] to do the vibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wanted to learn how to use vibrator and quickly wrote this program which does what you want. Vibrator permission has to be set in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> 


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Launch extends Activity {
    int dot = 100;         
    int dash = 220;              
    int short_gap = 200;             
    int medium_gap = 700; 
    int i = 0;
    long[] vibPattern = new long[] {0, dash, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, medium_gap};
    TextView vibIndicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vibIndicator = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        simpleTimer();
    }


    public void simpleTimer(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (vibPattern[i] == dot){                 
                   vibIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
                   vibratePhone(vibPattern[i]);
                }else if(vibPattern[i] == dash){                 
                   vibIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                   vibratePhone(vibPattern[i]);
                }else{
                     vibIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
                }   

                i++;
                if (i< vibPattern.length){
                    simpleTimer();           
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Launch.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
            }
        }, vibPattern[i]);  
    }

    public void vibratePhone(long timeLength){
        Vibrator vibrator;           
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);                  
        try{
            vibrator.vibrate(timeLength);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hey thanks trying it out now but seems promising, instead of using the long[] method u use a loop to do the vibration 1 by 1 and from there u can set the background colour easily

Comment: Yes in this way it is easily syncronised.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` gives no guarantee of how long it sleeps, you need to program this yourself, something like:

```
private void sleep(long ms) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` might only end up sleeping e.g., `1 ms` due to how the function is defined.

Comment: ah ic thanks for the heads up.  tried with your code and my application would still hang while vibrating and only display the last colour

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all the GUI updates before starting the vibration pattern. Therefor, it will only ever be showing the last state when doing the vibration pattern.

I haven't worked with Android before, so but I'm assuming that `vibrate()` blocks until the pattern has completed. If you still want to use that method, you will need to do it asynchronously so that the update loop is running in parallel. The other option would be to control the vibrator with more granularity and not use the pattern method. This way on each iteration, you decide if the vibrator needs to turn on or off and what that means to your GUI updates.